# JUnit integration test across GWT & Appengine devmodes, with RESTEasy

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, junit, resteasy

I want to run a test in which my GWT code makes a request to my AppEngine server and waits for a response.  My server uses RESTEasy to set up request paths.  My client uses some AutoBean magic, which uses GWT.create(), so this test has to be a GWTTestCase.

What do I need to do to set up a full simulation of the appengine development mode for my test?  The [docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting.html#Setting_Up_a_Testing_Framework) mention ways to set up each of the individual services that appengine relies on, but I want to spin up the whole thing.

Comment: YOu are going to make an integration test. This is no more the focus **JUNIT**

Comment: Based on my research, I don't think this is possible. You would think there would be some information here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting if it was.

Answer (score 0):

Being unfamiliar with GWTTestCase, I do not fully understand what do you need in here. Wouldn't a simple:

```
public class LocalDatastoreTest 
{
    private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper =
        new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig(),
                                   new LocalUserServiceTestConfig(),
                                   new LocalTaskQueueTestConfig(),
                                   new LocalMemcacheServiceTestConfig(),
                                   new LocalAppIdentityServiceTestConfig() // etc..
                                  );

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        helper.setUp();
    }
}
```

where you can add more test configs to the helper as required, be sufficient for setting up a `full simulation of the appengine development mode`? Could you provide more details on what you need?

(This should probably count as comment, but the code example I tried to wrote is too large for comments)

Comment: For example, after I set this up as you suggest, how can I simulate a request to the server and parse the response?

Answer (score 0):

Because in general programming tests work better through 3rd library *jars*:
The best thing to do is the following:

1. Just write your test cases by using `jUnit` *api* and get all the
   needed objects of your project from the parameters of methods and
   never initiate the objects locally
2. Build a `GWT` *jar* *plug-in* from your test cases by including
   `GWT` `XML` file in it
3. Add the *jar* in to your `class-paths`
4. Call the jar method by providing the parameter objects from within
   your own project packages
5. Your tests will work charmingly (neat, robust, and quick are only some words to your advantage all along the way!) with the least efforts

I hope it helps.